# Invalid argument error with stod

Tags: string, c++11

I'm getting the `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument` for `stod` function for the following lines of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string line = "5,,1,1,1";

    std::stringstream lineStream(line);
    std::string cell;
    std::string::size_type sz;

    while (std::getline(lineStream, cell, ','))
    {
       std::cout << std::stod(cell, &sz) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Can somebody point me out the reasons for the exact error?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I noticed that error is because of the space " " between two commas "," in the line. Now the question is: Does `getline` return space in the `cell` variable?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Using the above comment you can find out when you get the exception and let us know if it is not clear why you get the exception.

Comment: Are you sure that in `line` there isn't a `','` before the first number?

Comment: @NathanOliver. Dear Sir, Error is obviously at `stod`. The question is why? I feed some string like "45" and it works. But the string returned by `getline`  and kept in the `cell` variable is throwing error. Can you explain me why?

Comment: @Bob__. Its is CSV file I am reading line by line via getline.

Comment: In order to make your code sample a [mcve], you need to include a definition for `line` , preferably in your `main()` method.

Comment: What is the contents of `cell` when the exception happens?

Comment: @NathanOliver. I printed the content of `cell` and here is what I got. cell=5

Comment: @TobySpeight. MWE given.

Comment: Well, after 5, you have a double comma...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is you have an empty cell.  There is no conversion from empty to a valid `double` so `stod` throws an excpetion.  What you need to do is skip empty cells like

```
while(std::getline(lineStream, cell, ','))
{
    if (!cell.empty())
        cout<<stod(cell, &sz)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'll use the empty cell to fill `0`'s in the data I'm reading.

Comment: @chandresh Then do that in the else statement.  Since you know it is empty just output/store a 0.

Comment: Infact, I had done that but without using `.empty()` function I used `.compare(" ")` function but it does not work with spaces.